# Variations with repetition of r integers in {0...k} that sum to u

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, python-itertools, combinatorics

Given a set of integers `x = {0...k}`, I need to find the most efficient algorithm to generate all variations with repetition of `r` integers `x` that sum to `u`.

I thought to

```py
from itertools import product
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

k = 10
r = 5
u = 12
x = np.arange(0, k+1)

prod = product(x, repeat=r)
df = pd.DataFrame(list(prod))
print(f"VR{x.size, r} = {df.index.size} = (k+1)^r = {(k+1)**r}\n")

df = df[df.sum(axis=1)==u]
print(df)
```

```
VR(11, 5) = 161051 = (k+1)^r = 161051

         0  1  2  3   4
32       0  0  0  2  10
42       0  0  0  3   9
52       0  0  0  4   8
62       0  0  0  5   7
72       0  0  0  6   6
...     .. .. .. ..  ..
146652  10  0  2  0   0
147742  10  1  0  0   1
147752  10  1  0  1   0
147862  10  1  1  0   0
149072  10  2  0  0   0

[1795 rows x 5 columns]
```

But this is highly inefficient because the total number of variations with repetition  is `VR(k+1, r) = (k+1)^r` and generates a giant `df`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What should be the result? A giant file instead of a giant dataframe?

Comment: @MichaelButscher as you can see, the dataframe of all variations is `161051` lines but the result of needed variations that sum to `u` is `1795` lines. I'm asking if there is a more efficient algorithm to generate the result.

Comment: Usually that would be a recursive algorithm. Set leftmost integer to 0 and find all sequences of `r-1` integers with sum `u`. Then set leftmost integer to 1 and find all sequences of `r-1` integers with sum `u-1`...

Comment: Dynamic programming should solve this efficiently

Comment: @MichaelButscher thanks. I'll implement it and try.

Comment: @myrtlecat do you mean recursion, in this specific case, as suggested by @MichaelButscher?

Comment: Are all the integers positive, and is there a size limit on`u`?  This is basically a knapsack problem, and if `u` isn't too big, then the usual dynamic programming technique applies.

Comment: @MattTimmermans yes all integers are positive: usually `k` is small (from 2 to 30) but there is no limit on `r` and `u`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid creating all productions, you could bail out as soon as the sum can no longer be attained by adding remaining values to complete an r-tuple.

Here is a plain Python function that does that. I didn't compare its execution time with other solutions, but with the example parameters it returns a list within 0.003 seconds when running on repl.it. Of course, *printing* those entries will take time too:

```
def solve(greatest, count, target):
    collected = [0] * count
    if count <= 0 or count == 1 and target > greatest:
        return
    
    def recur(count, target):
        if count == 1:  # base case
            collected[-1] = target
            yield tuple(collected)
            return
        i = count - 1
        # Clip the range to values that still allow solutions
        for val in range(max(0, target - i * greatest), min(target, greatest) + 1):
            collected[-count] = val
            yield from recur(i, target - val)
            
    yield from recur(count, target)

# example run
from time import time
start = time()
result = list(solve(10, 5, 12))
print("done", time() - start)  # 0.003..... on repl.it
print(result)
```

Comment: This is about 25x faster than using a comprehension as in my suggestion. Note that if order is not relevant there are only 45 unique variations.

Comment: Thank you, this is the more efficient algorithm suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Although not a cleverer basic algorithm you can avoid Pandas and do it about 100x faster directly in Numpy and so avoid forming the giant DF and List:

```
res = [y for y in prod if sum(y) == u]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this too and compare it to @MichaelButscher suggestion.